# Ambiguous type variable but not in ghci?

Tags: haskell

Can anybody explain why haskell enforces explicit type signature in the following example and how to modify it to avoid need of the explicit declaration ?

```
import qualified Data.List as L

main = do
    print $ length $ L.nub [1,1,2,3]  -- 3, passed (Eq a, Num a) => [a]
    print $ length $ L.nub []         -- ambiguous type error, passed (Eq a) => [a]
    -- can help type system with explicit signature but how to avoid ?
    print $ length $ L.nub ([] :: [Int])
```

Surprisingly the same code written interactively in ghci has no issue with ambiguity and does prints zero length:

```
λ> :m +Data.List
λ> print $ length $ nub []
0  -- ?? can you explain ??
```

**Update:**
It seems even same restricted as `Data.List.nub` length function won't stop complaints about ambiguous type:

```
length' :: Eq a => [a] -> Int
length' [] = 0
length' (x:xs) = 1 + length' xs

main = do
    print $ length' $ nub []
-- No instance for (Eq a0) arising from a use of ‘length'’
-- The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
```

Comment: ghci turns on the extended default rules (`-XExtendedDefaultRules`)  by default, see [here](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.2/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html), go to section 2.4.8.

Comment: Thanks. Is that a hidden flag as ghci won't list it with `:show language` I get `base language is: Haskell2010
with the following modifiers:
  -XNoDatatypeContexts
  -XNondecreasingIndentation` ?

Comment: I think the rules are on only for interactive input and not for loaded modules, so the real compiler flag is not "really" on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `[]` has the polymorphic type `(Eq a) => [a]`. Since `length` doesn't add any particular constraint.

Specifically the type of `length` is:

```
length :: [a] -> Int
```

which is even more permissive than `nub`:

```
nub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
```

The compiler needs to use a specific instance of `length` there and is not able to deduce a type for `a`.

Now you have two options:

1. Turn on the `ExtendedDefaultRules` extension with `{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}` at the beginning of the file.
2. Be explicit: `... L.nub ([] :: [Int])`

I'd recommend the 2nd one by default, unless you fully understand the [consequences of the first one](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.2/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you also explain why equally specialized length function like `length' :: Eq a => [a] -> a` won't help and I am still getting ambiguous type error ?

Comment: @DavidUnric Because the compiler can't still deduce `a` because there are > 1 data types that satisfy `Eq` *equally* well (pun not intended). May I ask what book you are studying Haskell on? AFAIK most books talk about this topic in the first half.

Comment: Sure there are many instances of class `Eq`, just did expected the type system can infer from `[] :: Eq t => [t]` as enough for `length` as a generic type is enough to calculate list's length.

Comment: @DavidUnric A generic type is enough to calculate a list's length, which is why the standard length function doesn't have an Eq constraint! When you added the Eq constraint to your version, you *specifically declared* to GHC that it needs to come up with an Eq instance to be able to call the function. It can't do that without knowing what type `a` is (or being passed something of the smae type that also has the constraint). It assumes you meant what you said, rather than looking inside the definition of `length'` to see that you didn't 'really" need the instance, so it errors out.

Comment: re: "The compiler needs to use a specific instance of `length` there", didn't you mean `nub`?