# Ambiguous type variable in a test for empty list

Tags: haskell, empty-list

Consider the following snippet which defines a function `foo` which takes in a list and performs some operation on the list (like sorting).
I tried to load the snippet in `ghci`:

```
-- a function which consumes lists and produces lists
foo :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
foo [] = []
foo (x:xs) = xs

test1 = foo [1, 2, 3] == [2, 3]
test2 = null $ foo []
```

yet the following error occurs:

```
No instance for (Ord a0) arising from a use of ‘foo’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (Either a b)
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
      instance forall (k :: BOX) (s :: k). Ord (Data.Proxy.Proxy s)
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Proxy’
      instance (GHC.Arr.Ix i, Ord e) => Ord (GHC.Arr.Array i e)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Arr’
      ...plus 26 others
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘foo []’
    In the expression: null $ foo []
    In an equation for ‘test2’: test2 = null $ foo []
```

The problem is in the expression `test2 = null $ foo []`. Furthermore, removing `Ord a` constraint from the type definition of `foo` will solve the problem. Strangely, typing `null $ foo []` in the *interactive* mode (after loading the definition for `foo`) works correctly and produces the expected `true`.

I need a clear explanation for this behaviour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambiguous type variable but not in ghci?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467291/ambiguous-type-variable-but-not-in-ghci)

Comment: @WillNess: Thanks. Yet, as you can see this "test" is meaningless because it is already in the definition of the function. I need only to understand why that error occurs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like thinking of typeclasses in "dictionary-passing style".  The signature

```
foo :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
```

says that `foo` takes a dictionary of methods for `Ord a`, essentially as a parameter, and a list of `a`s, and gives back a list of `a`s.  The dictionary has things in it like `(<) :: a -> a -> Bool` and its cousins.  When we call `foo`, we need to supply such a dictionary.  This is done implicitly by the compiler. So

```
foo [1,2,3]
```

will use the `Ord Integer` dictionary, because we know that `a` is `Integer`.

However, in `foo []`, the list could be a list of anything -- there is no information to determine the type.  But we still need to find the `Ord` dictionary to pass to `foo` (although your `foo` doesn't use it at all, the signature says that it could, and that's all that matters).  That's why there is an ambiguous type error.  You can specify the type manually, which will give enough information to fill in the dictionary, like this

```
null (foo ([] :: [Integer]))
```

or with the new `TypeApplications` extension

```
null (foo @Integer [])
```

If you remove the `Ord` constraint, it works, as you have observed, and this is just because we no longer need to supply a dictionary.  We don't need to know what specific type `a` is to call `foo` anymore (this feels a little magical to me :-).

Note that `foo ([] :: Ord a => [a])` does *not* eliminate the ambiguity, because it is not known which specific `Ord` dictionary you want to pass; is it `Ord Int` or `Ord (Maybe String)`, etc.? There is *no* generic `Ord` dictionary, so we have to choose, and there is *no* rule for what type to choose in this case. Whereas when you say `(Ord a, Num a) => [a]`, then defaulting specifies a way to choose, and we pick `Integer`, since it is a special case of the `Num` class.

The fact that `foo []` works in `ghci` is due to `ghci`’s [extended defaulting](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules) rules. It might be worth reading about [type defaulting](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-04-type-defaulting-in-haskell.html) in general, which is surely not the prettiest part of Haskell, but it is going to come up a lot in the kinds of corner cases you are asking about.

Comment: but why should the type of the list matter for `null`?
and it is clear that `foo` produces a list of type `Ord a => [a]`; isn't that enough for the compiler?

Comment: strangely, if one enters `null $ foo []` in the _interactive_ mode (after loading the definition of `foo`), it works without any problem.

Comment: @AlQuemist, it doesn't matter for `null`, it matters for `foo`.  And `foo` *consumes* the `Ord a` dictionary, that is the problem (we don't have one).

Comment: The fact that it works in `ghci` is due to `ghci`'s [extended defaulting rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules).  It might be worth reading about [type defaulting](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-04-type-defaulting-in-haskell.html) in general, which is surely not the prettiest part of Haskell, but it's going to come up a lot in the kinds of corner cases you are asking about.

Comment: why can't the compiler infer the type of `[]` in the test expression?
shouldn't that be obvious from the definition of `foo`; namely, `foo :: Ord a => [a] -> [a];
foo [] = []` ?
I think the type is obvious; no need for further ado.

Comment: to pass a "dictionary" along with the empty list, could we use `foo ([] :: Ord a => [a])` to remove ambiguity?

Comment: I found that something list `test3 = null $ foo ([] :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a])` solves the issue.

Comment: @AlQuemist that's also because of defaulting.  That type will just end up defaulting to `[Integer]` because it includes `Num`.  It's a bit roundabout; I'd just use a concrete type like `[Integer]` directly, though it doesn't really matter what type you use, you could use something crazy like `null $ foo ([] :: [Either Integer String])`.  To me the most elegant choice is `null $ foo ([] :: [`[`Void`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/void-0.7.1/docs/Data-Void.html)`])`, because it says very directly that the list must empty (modulo `undefined`).

Comment: could you explain what the defining relation, `foo :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]; foo [] = []` mean to the _compiler_? I imagine that this would be enough for the compiler to correctly interpret the type of `[]`, in an expression like `res = foo []`. Why doesn't the compiler reduce the polymorphic type of `[]` to the correct type (e.g., `[Void]`)? Such a reduction happens, for instance, when one calls a function `bar :: Float -> Float` on a “polymorphic constant” like `2` (the deduced type will be `Float`, rather than `Integer`).

Comment: @AlQuemist did you read about [defaulting](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-04-type-defaulting-in-haskell.html) yet?

Comment: could you please explain why `foo ([] :: Ord a => [a])` does _not_ eliminate the ambiguity, while passing the required “dictionary”?

Comment: @AlQuemist because it is not known which specific `Ord` dictionary you want to pass.  Is it `Ord Int` or `Ord (Maybe String)` or what?  There is no generic `Ord` dictionary, only for specific `a`s, so we have to choose, and there is no rule for what type to choose in this case.   Whereas whn you say `(Ord a, Num a) => [a]`, then defaulting specifies a way to choose, and we pick `Integer`.  It's a special case of the `Num` class.